# Python script is returning FileNotFoundError on Mac, but not Linux

Tags: python, linux, macos

I am having an error with my script. I am on Linux (Ubuntu), and my script runs fine... but when I send it to someone who uses macOS, they get this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mytext.txt'`

```py
with open('mytext.txt', 'r') as f:
    file = f.readlines()
```

Of course, both me (and Google) thought it was because of relative path. I changed it to absolute path, but same error.

```py
import os
with open(os.getcwd() + '/mytext.txt', 'r') as f:
    file = f.readlines()
```

Well, that didn't work. Kept searching, and I tried this solution:

```py
import os
path_name = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'mytext.txt')

with open(path_name, 'r') as f:
    file = f.readlines()
```

...but that didn't work either.

Any ideas as to why this may be? Every iteration of the script worked for me, the Linux user, but not for the macOS user. Is there something I'm missing about Linux and macOS Python script cross-compatibility, or something in my actual code I'm just doing wrong? And yes, I am sure there is a `mytext.txt` in the exact same directory as the actual script for both of us. Thanks for assisting me!

**Edit**: When trying to get help with this question in a different location, someone asked for the full error. In case it helps, here it is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/drive2/test/mytext.py", line 15, in <module>
    with open(path_name, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Volumes/drive2/test/mytext.txt'
```

And to reiterate, it works fine for me (and other people who are not on macOS). Error only applies for the person trying to run this on macOS.

Comment: How is the user running the script? Try `cat mytest.txt`

Comment: Are you and the other user both running the script from the same directory?  On MacOS, the default directory is the location where the user is when they are running the script, not the location of the script.  I think this is also the case for Linux (I can't check now), so is it possible that you're in the right directory already, or you've made a copy of mytext.py, and your friend isn't/hasn't?

Comment: `No such file or directory: '/Volumes/drive2/test/mytext.txt'` - the file is simply not there. Please double check. Also the name (possible gotchas: trailing space, homoglyphs, non-printable chars).

Comment: To be honest im surprised it works anywhere.  To open a file you need to know its path, on all systems.  None of your paths here are very “solid”:  os.getcwd() + '/mytext.txt' is current directory, os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'mytext.txt' is a sibling of python file.  Macos is the same as Linux file wise.  I suggest your hardcode the macos actual file name and work back from there.  2 extra things:  are there spaces in the directory names?  What are the **read permissions** for the file?

Comment: did you send `mytext.txt` with your code to other users? Other users may not have file `mytext.txt`. Is your code working on your computer when you delete `mytext.txt`?  Maybe all problem is that you already have `mytext.txt` but other users don't have it. Maybe your code should first check if file exists and then read it or inform that file doesn't exist - or it should create empty file `mytext.txt`. You could also use `os.listdir(folder)` to see what have other users in folder.

Comment: Agreement with @furas.... directory is obviously good, and needed file is obviously not inside of it.

Comment: Are the file acess rights good ?

Answer (score 0):

So I tested this solution here that you proposed on a macOS with jupyter notebook:

```
import os
with open(os.getcwd() + '/mytext.txt', 'r') as f:
    file = f.readlines()
```

and it worked just fine for me, so this is not a macOS problem. The person that is trying to run this has to make sure that both the notebook/ python script as well as the .txt file are in the same folder though.